# How to get numeric month from date (the date format: both D.MM.YYYY and DD.MM.YYYY)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to get a numeric month to the next-to cell from Date text of previous cell. Example: 1.3.2020 should result, in new cell, as 3

I cannot use MID function due to two reasons: First is that the type of value in relevant cell is not Text or General but it is Date. Second is that days are in one entire column in both formats DD (two digits) and D (one digit). Example: sometimes is January typed as 1 and sometimes as 01.

I cannot use SEARCH function due to three reasons: First: it's for advanced users and I'm just a beginner. Second: sometimes is Month typed in format MM and sometimes M. Third: I have no idea how to get the text that would be between first and second **dot** (from left to right) so I could get the month. E.g. D.MM.YYY (to get MM in numeric).

What else could I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the original date information is in cell A1, in cell B1 (or wherever), enter:
=MONTH(A1)

Aside: If your dates all have slightly different formatting you can fix that to make it more consistent for reading / alignment. Just select all the cells with dates and reformat as number format "Short date" which by default is always dd/mm/yyyy (rather than d/m/yyyy).